# I'm looking for a low budget current sensors for AC

Tags: transformer, current-measurement

I'm looking for a low budget (< 10$ per sensor) sensor for measuring AC current up to 20 A. I found many current transformers but they go up to 5 or 10 A.

Any idea what types would fit? Compensation, hall effect, current transformers?

My precision requirements are not very high... 2 to 3 % is enough.

Answer (score 4):

Consider isolated in-line current sensors such as the Allegro Micro [ACS712](http://www.allegromicro.com/Products/Current-Sensor-ICs/Zero-To-Fifty-Amp-Integrated-Conductor-Sensor-ICs/ACS712.aspx):

These current sensors work with AC or DC, and add just 1.2 milliOhms to the current path. Line isolation is 2.1 kV RMS, so your circuitry on the sensing side is safe from line voltages. There are 5 Ampere, 20 Ampere and 30 Ampere versions of the IC.

The device is also available as [prebuilt modules on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/20A-range-Current-Sensor-Module-ACS712-Module-NEW-/130704793585?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1e6e9cdff1) (*$2.98 shipped*), for a much lower price than single units of the bare IC [on DigiKey](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/ACS712ELCTR-20A-T/620-1190-1-ND/1284607) (*$4.34 + shipping*).

Comment: I've used these before. Though they work, they are very susceptible to any type of magnetic noise. You place a magnet near these or have a motor running near these and they'll output lots of noise. For the AC version of the IC, I think you're going to have to rectify the output. It doesn't automatically output DC for you.

Comment: @NothinRandom The 5 Ampere device is somewhat magnetism sensitive - but it isn't a noise, merely a tiny bias voltage on the output unless the magnet is being moved. I have a 20 Ampere part here that I just waved a rare-earth magnet around, and got no discernible noise.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just ordered 2 of the ebay modules and I will test them as soon as they arrive. They look very promising, and for 3$ per module I can easily measure my entire home

Answer (score 2):

A possibility, since you mentioned AC, is a *current transformer*.  The primary only has a turn or a few turns, so presents very little impedance, especially when the secondary is nearly shorted.

Some current transformers only come with the secondary, which is wound around a torus.  The hole thru the middle of the torus is deliberately left open and available to the outside so that you simply run whatever wire you want to measure current in thru the hole.  Since you want to measure 20 A, this type might be fine.

You put the primary in-line wherever you want to measure the current.  The transformer inherently isolates the secondary, so that can be tied directly to whatever circuit you want, floating with a different power supply.

Current transformers only work with AC current, preferably one at known fixed frequency.  But, that describes line power very well, which is why current tranformers are often used to sense current in the power line or in the power feed to a device.

Answer (score 1):

You might split the conductor into two lengthwise and place a 10A current transformer only around half of the conductor.  You would need to calibrate more carefully, since you can't guarantee that 50% of the power will pass through that half of the conductor.